# How to determine if DPC++ compiler works with intel MKL?

Tags: c++, intel-mkl, dpc++

I try to use intel MKL with DPC++  compiler, and reports

> "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF61B91397A in test_parallel.exe:
> 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000002239F286444."

Below is my code to test MKL function:

```cpp
int main()
{
    //cl::sycl::stream cout(1024, 256);
    int a = 1, b = 1;
    int n = 5;
    float* A = (float*)mkl_malloc(n * 1 * sizeof(float), 64);
    float* B = (float*)mkl_malloc(n * 1 * sizeof(float), 64);
    printf("The 1st vector is ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        A[i] = i;
        printf("%2.0f", A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("The 2st vector is ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        B[i] = i + 1;
        printf("%2.0f", B[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    //compute:a*A+b*B
    cblas_saxpby(n, a, A, 1, b, B, 1);
    printf("The a*A+b*B is ");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) //this is where the above error is reported
    {
        printf("%2.0f", B[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    mkl_free(A);
    mkl_free(B);
    //getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The above code works when I use Intel C++ compiler, and I am sure intel DPC++ compiler is correctly installed because I have tested a vector-add program before.

**I wonder if DPC++ compiler works with Intel MKL.**

Comment: Based on their [documentation](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-reference-dpcpp/2023-0/overview.html) DCP++ and Intel oneMKL can work together.

Try to debug your application why this error happening to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will check the document to find out what's wrong with my application!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [asked this question](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Math-Kernel-Library/whether-DPC-compiler-works-with-intel-MKL/m-p/1490310) in the Intel forum and the moderator solved this problem.

The problem is caused by my project property setting: I used the DPC++ API instead of the "ILP64" interface, which make things go wrong.

[image]